# Why I get this errors when I install Sitecore 9?

Tags: installation, sitecore, sitecore9

[image]

I following official documentation - "Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0 Update 1", and after running the powershell script below

```
 ...
#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
} 
18: Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose <----------------

#install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
    Name = "SC9"
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 
...
```

I get errors...I can't understood what I do wrong. Help me please!

Comment: Try to use SIF 1.2.1 `Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 1.2.1`

Comment: @MarekMusielak, Thank you for the suggestion, but I using it now. Sitecore 9.0.0 and SIF 1.2.1

Comment: Check your certificates if you don't have multiple DO_NOT_TRUST certificates on your machine

Comment: Make sure that SIF 1.2.1 is the *only* installed version of the module. If you previously installed 2.x by accident, you will need to remove it from your system.